# Incorrect sliding window algorithm (in python)

Tags: python, algorithm, sliding-window

While trying this question: https://leetcode.com/problems/permutation-in-string/

> "Given two strings s1 and s2, return true if s2 contains a permutation
> of s1, or false otherwise.
>
> In other words, return true if one of s1's permutations is the
> substring of s2."

I came up with a sliding window solution, but I did not want to use an additional hash table for keeping track of the letters in the current window. I am struggling to figure out why it is not correct.

Fails with this example: `"trinitrophenylmethylnitramine" "dinitrophenylhydrazinetrinitrophenylmethylnitramine"`

```
class Solution:
    def checkInclusion(self, s1: str, s2: str) -> bool:
        
        s1_ht = {}
        for char in s1:
            if char in s1_ht:
                s1_ht[char] += 1
            else:
                s1_ht[char] = 1
        
        start = 0
        counter = len(s1_ht)
        
        for i in range(0, len(s2), 1):
                
            if s2[i] in s1_ht:
                s1_ht[s2[i]] -= 1
                if s1_ht[s2[i]] == 0:
                    counter -= 1
            
            if i - start + 1 == len(s1):
                    
                if counter == 0:
                    return True
                
                if s2[start] in s1_ht:
                    s1_ht[s2[start]] += 1
                    if s1_ht[s2[start]] > 0:
                        counter += 1
                        
                start += 1
        
        
        return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great solution. But there is a minor mistake here:

```py
if s1_ht[s2[start]] > 0:
   counter += 1
```

In these lines of code, you increment the counter although `s1_ht[ s2[start] ]` was not zero before the incrementation. Let me explain with an example. Suppose `s1_ht['t'] = 4`. Then you find `s2[start] = 't'`. Therefore you increment `s1_ht['t']` and set it equal to 5. But then you increment the counter which leads to an error. You shouldn't increment the counter since it already covers the character `'t'`. Swap that line with this:

```py
if s1_ht[s2[start]] == 1:   # just before the incrementation, it was zero
   counter += 1
```

It passes the Leetcode test cases with 61 ms runtime and 14 MB memory on my machine.